# Windows 8 Unidentified network on direct wired connection

Tags: windows-8, home-networking, file-sharing

Having a laptop and desktop, both installed Windows 8 x86. I have Ethernet cable which is plugged directly without any router or any other device. I've followed this steps : http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers-Together-with-an-Ethernet-Cable to share files from one machine to another. But I'm seeing only laptop name on the network folder of laptop, and desktop name on the desktop's network folder.

I ensured:

1. Both having same work group name.
2. Turned on the sharing option on "Unidentified network" item on network connections list.

Edit

- I can access PC 'A' folder from PC 'B', but can't do it in vice versa
- Can't see A on B's network folder neither B on A's network folder.
- A's folder can be accessed only by navigating to `\A\foldername`. Not by visible folders/clicks.

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off topic, so I removed that to ensure your question doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 0):

On both computers, please create a new folder, both called Test.

Right click on the folders, share it AND ensure permissions are set to everyone (with full control).

If this works, then it just means you haven't shared the folders you want to share.

Or, in Windows explorer, type `\\ComputerName\c$` and see if that helps.

Comment: 1) I got desktop folder on laptop but not vice versa. 2) I can't see deskop on networks folder (of laptop), but can access it through url `\\computername\folder`

Comment: what happens if you type in \\computername\c$

Comment: It's prompting for pass. I supplied desktop credentials as computer\user with pass. Throws me an error 'Not accessible' with no permission message.

Comment: OK, so we now know the issue is a permissions issue. Back to the computer, right click on Test folder and select properties. In the sharing tab, click advanced sharing. Share this folder, click permissions, and select everyone and give them Full Control. Click APPLY. Now, right click on Test -> Properties and select security tab. Click Edit, Add. type everyone and click OK. Give them full control. Now try to access it again from other PC

Comment: Thanks. But problems seems not like that. I've edited the question for more info.